# tcl : execute git command

Tags: git, shell, tcl

I want to download my git repo unsing tcl.
I use this proc

```
proc download_git_repo {} { 
    global git_rev git_path
    exec git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git $git_path/bit_git
}
```

but I can't found the directory bit_git, it seems the command exec doesn't works fine with git!

I used exec for other comand it's works fine

how can I excecute git command in shell with tcl

Comment: Is $git_path set correctly? How do you enter username and password?

Comment: I fancy the `git_path` variable has spaces in its value or it's not absolute and your script happens to have a working directory different from the one you expect at the time the script runs (or it calls `cd` somewhere before the call to `download_git_repo`).  Make sure you have the `GIT_TRACE` enviroment variable set to `1` and *exported* before calling your script (to that Git sees it) and see what Git will print out while cloning.

Comment: Consider reading [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/exec) and pay attention to various methods presented there for properly delimiting distinct arguments to `exec`.

Comment: I tested with command under tclsh it's works but when I use script it doesn't !!

Comment: @kostix, I don't understand your concern: there's no `eval` here so the value of `$git_path/bit_git` should get passed to git as a single argument.

Comment: Also `set ::env(GIT_TRACE) 1; exec git ...` will be enough to get that variable into the environment for git.

Comment: @glennjackman, yes, you're correct. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely option is that you're not in the directory that you think you are. It's ever so easy to get that wrong when you go to scripting things; for example, programs invoked directly from a GUI tend to run in quite different locations to what you're expecting.

I advise writing the value you're about to pass into `git clone` into a variable and then logging that somewhere:

```
proc download_git_repo {} { 
    global git_rev git_path
    set theLocation $git_path/bit_git
    puts "working dir: [pwd]\nlocation: $the_location"
    # Use this instead if inside a Tk script:
    # tk_messageBox -message "working dir: [pwd]\nlocation: $the_location"
    exec git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git $the_location
}
```

Like that, you can see exactly what you are really giving to git. I advise making sure that it is an absolute path; those *don't* surprise.

And while Tcl is very careful to handle things like spaces in filenames correctly (unless you `eval`; don't do that!) it's not always the case that other tools are so careful.